# Deleting a row depending on the value of a specific column

Tags: mysql

I want to delete a row of data if in a specific column the value is 1.

For example I have a Table called 'Table1' and it has 3 columns: 'ID' 'Value' and 'Process'.I constanly log data to this table

```
ID | Value | Process
1  |  30   |    0
2  |  24   |    0
3  |  26   |    1
4  |  34   |    0
```

Is it possible to when a 1 is logged to 'Process' this Row automatically gets deleted ?

Comment: Why do you insert it in the table in the first place, if you want to get it immediately deleted

Comment: It is  not inserted manually

Comment: Offcourse, nobody inserts manually. You should firstly look to fix the code which inserts it; instead of looking to delete it afterwards.

Comment: You could use a trigger that signals an error, to prevent the row from being inserted.

Comment: It is kinda inserted manually, its originally all 0 but when we want to delete those specific rows we send a 1 in ‘process’ instead of going into mySQL to delete it manually.

Comment: @kneth: *"its originally all 0 but when we want to delete those specific rows we send a 1"* - So the record doesn't get inserted with a 1?  Then trying to immediately delete records inserted with a 1 won't exactly work.  It's not really clear to me what you're describing or what the problem is.  If you want a record inserted, you insert it.  If you want a record updated, you update it.  If you want a record deleted, you delete it.  What isn't working?

Comment: no it does not get inserted with 1 always a 0 . the record stay until we want to delete them. When we want to delete them we will send a 1 into 'Process' to delete that row.

Comment: @kneth: Ok, so what specifically are you asking?

Comment: how to delete those rows if there is a 1 in 'Process' without going to mySQL and delete them manually.

Comment: @kneth: `DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE Process = 1`  You don't have to execute this manually, you can execute it from code.